# Mysql query subselect getting NULL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join over three tables and get the active plan of a vendor. It is possible, that the vendor had a lot of plans in the past, but the active on is that counts.
The whole query is bigger (counting items he has aso) and because of that i did it with a subselect, but for this example it should be enough.

I always get plantitle and planstatus of NULL. How can i fix this?

Query

```
SELECT v.title
     , plans.title AS plantitle
     , uplans.status AS planstatus
     , uplans.uid
     , COUNT(DISTINCT obs.id) AS obj_count
     , sum(case when obs.published = -1 then 1 else 0 end) trash
     , sum(case when obs.published = 1 then 1 else 0 end) published
     , sum(case when obs.published = 0 then 1 else 0 end) unpublished
FROM `vendors` AS v    
LEFT JOIN objects AS obs ON obs.vid = v.id
LEFT JOIN `userplans` AS uplans ON uplans.uid = (
  SELECT up.id
  FROM `userplans`AS up
  WHERE up.uid=v.uid AND status = "ACTIVE" LIMIT 1) 
LEFT JOIN `plans` AS plans ON plans.id=uplans.pid
GROUP BY v.id
ORDER BY v.id asc
```

Tables

```
Vendors
id, uid, title
10,  1, Name 1
20,  4, Name 2
30,  5, Name 3

Plans
id, title
40, Plan 1
50, Plan 2

Userplans
id, uid, pid, status
1, 1, 40, CANCELED
2, 1, 50, CANCELED
3, 1, 40, CANCELED
4, 4, 50, CANCELED
5, 4, 50, CANCELED
6, 4, 50, ACTIVE 
7, 1, 40, ACTIVE
```

Comment: does a plan only and always have one active status and user?

Comment: Why do you need the left joins?  V.userID = UP.UID, UP.PID = P.ID  where UP.status = 'ACTIVE' seems like it would return all vendors who have active user plans along with plan title...

Comment: updated the query

Comment: Is it possible that a userplans has no active status for a given user? (this would explain why you have null names) also Why the left joins?  Do you want all vendors including those perhaps without any userplans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets get the object counts 1st as the associations to other tables may be 1-M which would result in larger counts.  then join to the other needed information.

This still assumes that a the combination of a user and plan in userPlan can only have 1 active record.  If it can have more than 1 I still need to know which active userPlan to select.

Also why the left joins? are you after all vendors regardless of plans and objects and userplans?  Is it possible that a vendor HAS no active plans in which case the title would be null?

```
SELECT v.title
     , P.title AS plantitle
     , UP.status AS planstatus
     , up.uid
     , O.obj_count
     , O.trash
     , O.published
     , O.unpublished
FROM vendors v    
LEFT JOIN userplans  UP
  ON V.uid = UP.UID
 AND UP.status = 'ACTIVE'
LEFT JOIN (SELECT obs.VID
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT obs.id) AS obj_count
            ,sum(case when obs.published = -1 then 1 else 0 end) trash
            ,sum(case when obs.published = 1 then 1 else 0 end) published
            ,sum(case when obs.published = 0 then 1 else 0 end) unpublished
            FROM OBJECTS obs
            GROUP BY obs.VID) O  
  ON O.vid = v.id
LEFT JOIN `plans` P 
  ON P.id=UP.pid

ORDER BY v.id asc
```

---

And to address the comment to get the "Latest" Plan regardless of status (assuming latest would have the highest ID in the userPlans table.

```
SELECT v.title
     , P.title AS plantitle
     , UP.status AS planstatus
     , up.uid
     , O.obj_count
     , O.trash
     , O.published
     , O.unpublished
FROM vendors v    
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * -- though really we should just pull in the columns needed. 
            FROM USERPLANS U1 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT max(ID) ID, PID, UID 
                        FROM UserPlans 
                        GROUP BY PID, UID) U2 
              on  U1.ID = U2.ID) UP
  ON V.uid = UP.UID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT obs.VID
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT obs.id) AS obj_count
            ,sum(case when obs.published = -1 then 1 else 0 end) trash
            ,sum(case when obs.published = 1 then 1 else 0 end) published
            ,sum(case when obs.published = 0 then 1 else 0 end) unpublished
            FROM OBJECTS obs
            GROUP BY obs.VID) O  
  ON O.vid = v.id
LEFT JOIN `plans` P 
  ON P.id=UP.pid

ORDER BY v.id asc
```

Comment: Thanks, but like i said, i think i need the subselect because of the whole query. i extendet the query a bit so you can maybe better understand.

Comment: Yes it is possible that a vendor has no plan. I will try your approach and get back to you. thanks so far!

Comment: If a vendor has no plan, it has no title.  the only way to get to plans is though user plans, and thus no title.

Comment: Both is possible. Vendors without plans (so no userplan entries) and vendors with plans.

Comment: Is it possible that `FROM OBJECTS obs` is needed?

Comment: yes I need to aliases the subquery on the second to last join (doing so now) otherwise the case statements fail as they don't know obs is objects table.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how it would look like if i wanted to show the LATEST usersplan of every vendor regardless of its status.

Comment: Just change userPlans to a subquery like `(SELECT *
 FROM USERPLANS U1
 INNER JOIN (Select max(ID) ID, PID, UID from UserPlans group by PID, UID)  U2
 on U1.ID = U2.ID) UP`  and remove the status = active check on the on clause

Comment: man, where did you learn this? looking for a job? thanks anyways ;)

Comment: @Mike Thanks, that's humbling. 10+ years of Programming/SQL experience.  I love data mining, and RDBMS.  Set base logic and Lateral thinking problems have always been a passion of mine.   Can't say I'm looking for a Job, I'm in a good place at this time; as I can work on what I need to and I'm afforded the time to help out here from time to time as well.  Good luck on all the endeavors and I hope we helped!

Answer (score 0):

In your join of userplans - you are joining uplans.uid with the selected id from the same table - you need to join on the same column - change the line to :

```
LEFT JOIN `userplans` AS uplans ON uplans.id = (
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT Vendors.title, Plans.title, Userplans.status, Userplans.uid FROM Vendors, Plans, Userplans
WHERE Vendors.uid = Userplans.uid AND Plans.id = Userplans.pid AND Userplans.status = 'Active'
```

This assumes that you can only ever have one Active per user

Comment: Try to improve your solution with a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f58e7